# How can I remove forward slash(es) from an array of strings in Python?

Tags: python

I have an array as such

```
arrayOne = ['["https:\/\/somewebsite.com"]','["https:\/\/anotherwebsite.com"]', '["https:\/\/lastwebsite.com"]']
```

Essentially, what I am trying to do is remove the forward slash `\` from the strings in the array above. I am a python beginner so I am learning as I go. Is there a method in python that can do this? I am using python 3.9.

Successful output would look like this:

```
arrayTwo = ['["https://somewebsite.com"]','["https://anotherwebsite.com"]', '["https://lastwebsite.com"]']
```

Any guidance would be helpful!

Thank you very much!

Comment: (1) That's a backslash, a.k.a. "antivirgule".  (2) Use the `replace` method to convert them to the empty string.

Comment: A better question might be, where did that list of strings come from in the first place? Why were the forward slashes escaped for no apparent reason?

Comment: @Prune - I tried arrayOne.replace('/', '') it works when not in array but doesn't when in an array. I get: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: @chepner - great question haha, i am trying to resolve for it in a .csv file I got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use replace method for string object. Then use list comprehension for each web url in array.

```
arrayOne = [each.replace("\\","") for each in arrayOne]
```

Comment: This did it! Wow, I would like to know why it needed double slash ? Thank you very much @udoedo (and all) Appreciate it !!

Comment: You are welcome :) Because one backlash is used as an escape character. You can see it in : https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp